# Arbitrary string to valid Python name

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm trying to autogenerate Python code based on external data. Task is to convert arbitrary string to valid Python name.

I've come up with compact solution which seems to be technically correct:

```
import string

VALID_NAME_CHARACTERS = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits
PLACEHOLDER = "_"


def to_name(s):
    return ''.join(c.lower() if c in VALID_NAME_CHARACTERS else PLACEHOLDER for c in s).lstrip(string.digits)
```

Some testcases:

```
assert to_name("abcd123") == "abcd123" 
assert to_name("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet") == "lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet"
assert to_name(u"unicode-żółć") == "unicode_____"
assert to_name("123abcd") == "abcd"  # currently code does this
assert to_name("123abcd") == "___abcd"  # although I'd like to behave it like this
```

I'm a little bothered with non-consistent handling of digits on string starting digits.

Is there an simple way to make last testcase pass?

Comment: You only need to replace a digit in the 0th position with an underscore to make it a valid identifier, so just special-case that before the one-liner and remove the `lstrip`. `to_name("123abcd")` should result in `"_23abcd"`, assuming you want the minimal change to a valid identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only first character in Python name is forbidden to be a digit, we need to take care only of this special case.

```
import string

VALID_NAME_CHARACTERS = string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits
PLACEHOLDER = "_"


def to_name(s):
    if s[0] in string.digits:
        s = PLACEHOLDER + s[1:]
    return ''.join(c.lower() if c in VALID_NAME_CHARACTERS else PLACEHOLDER for c in s)
```

All test cases are passing, with all result names being valid Python identifiers:

```
assert to_name("abcd123") == "abcd123" 
assert to_name("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet") == "lorem_ipsum_dolor_sit_amet"
assert to_name(u"unicode-żółć") == "unicode_____"
assert to_name("123abcd") == "_23abcd"
```

Comment: How about python keywords such as `if`?

Comment: Stdlib contains [`keyword`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/keyword.html) module which should be enough to detect if string is a keyword and handle it correctly. Was not happening for my input data though :)